# Using the decrypted JSON from response in JSR223 Postprocessor(Groovy) - Jmeter

Tags: json, encryption, groovy, jmeter

I am hitting a request and the response is encrypted.When I decrypt the response in as JsonString and store it in Jmeter variable.I am able to extract value from it through JSON extractor.But when I use the variable in Postprocessor and try to extract value it throws error.

Decrypted Response :"_data" :[ {"name" : "mani","no" : 6}]

My Groovy Code:
def json =vars.get("response")   //response is the jmeter variable which contains decrypted response

```
if(!json._data[0].name!= "test"){
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("test is not passed");
 }
```

My error :

```
  javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _data for class: java.lang.String
```

Comment: Does `json.name` work?  I don't see where youre getting the `_data` from?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this line:

```
def json =vars.get("response")
```

to this one:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get("response"))
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)